# How to consume all messages from RabbitMQ in PHP

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I follow [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html) official `RabbitMQ` example for `PHP`. At the final step I open one console window and start sending messages and I open two console windows where I run

```
php receive.php
```

Then I start sending dozens of messages, however, I see, that only a small part of them is consumed. What I want is to consume them all. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you checked are there any messages that are unacked? in the web UI would be easiest

Comment: Could you provide more information? Screenshots of how you can tell that only some of them are consumed?